# How can we output in console all of the array of struct elements?

Tags: c#

I recently started learning c#. Could you please help me with writing a correct loop, in order to print all of the elements.

```
class Program
{        
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {            
        Arrays[] arr = new Arrays[500]; //Initialize an array
        arr[2].X = 11;     

        foreach (var i in arr) //Trying to loop through
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i); //Result: Array.Array
        }
    }
}
public struct Arrays
{
    public Int32 X, Y;        
}
```

Comment: What's the problem? Loop itself or output format or exceptions?

Comment: What do you *expect* the output to be, and why? (Hint: you haven't overridden the `ToString()` method, so you're just printing out whatever the default implementation does. Either override `ToString()`, or use `Console.WriteLine("X: {0}, Y: {1}", i.X, i.Y);`. I'd also strongly advise against mutable value types and public fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could for example override the ToString() method of your struct or access the properties of your Arrays in the `Console.WriteLine(i);` statement.

```
class Program
{        
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {            
        Arrays[] arr = new Arrays[500]; //Initialize an array
        arr[2].X = 11;     

        foreach (var i in arr) //Trying to loop through
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i); //Result: Array.Array
        }
    }
}
public struct Arrays
{
    public Int32 X, Y;      

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return X + " x " + Y;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The defaul `ToString()` implementation of an object will only output the object's type, that's why you simply see `Array.Array`.

You have two options:

1. Do the formatting in the loop itself:

   ```
   foreach (var i an arr) {
     Console.WriteLine("X: {0}, Y: {1}", i.X, i.Y);
   }
   ```
2. Override `ToString` with a custom implementation:

   ```
   public struct Arrays
   {
      public Int32 X, Y;

      public override string ToString() {
        return string.Format("X: {0}, Y: {1}", this.X, this.Y);
      }
   }
   ```

As an aside, public fields are considered bad design. Public properties are the better option.

Answer (score 1):

The `Console.WriteLine(i);` method expects an argument of type `System.String`. When you provide an struct of type `Arrays` to it it implicitly converts it into `String` by calling the `ToString` method that every struct or object has. By default, it just prints the name of the type - exactly what you see.
You can override the `ToString` method to change the output.

```
public struct Arrays
{
    public Int32 X, Y;

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return X.ToString() + " " + Y.ToString();
    }
}
```